# React, unit testing jquery + jquery print plugin in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, reactjs

I have a mocha + chai test suite set up for unit testing in my react app. This has been working great, however I am trying to cover one small bit of new code and am not sure how to best approach this. I have a small function that calls jquery and a jquery plugin to print a page. The code looks like so :

```
 printAsset() {
    const iframeDocument = $('#previewForPrint').contents().find('body');

    $.print(iframeDocument, {
        globalStyles: false,
        mediaPrint: true,
        stylesheet: null,
        noPrintSelector: "scrispt",
        iframe: true,
        append: null,
        prepend: null,
        manuallyCopyFormValues: true
    });
}
```

This functionality works fine, however I cannot seem to find a way to correctly unit test this. A few important things to note are that the `jquery` and `jquery.print` are not installed in the package.json, they are bower components that are loaded on the index.html. So when running my unit test i don't believe i have access to jquery and the print jquery addon. Here is my test  :

```
  it('fires print when the print button is clicked', () => {
    const previewCAS = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<PrintAsset />);
    const button = TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(PrintAsset, 'button');

    TestUtils.Simulate.click(button[0]);
    // breaks here
    // expect(Print).to.have.been.called();
});
```

This breaks with : ReferenceError: $ is not defined . So, I understand this, jquery is not imported uptop because its global with bower, however I am unsure how I am suppose to test this otherwise with the current suite. Is there a better way to do this or alternative approaches? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading!